# "Julio and I" vs "I and Julio"

Tags: grammaticality, word-order, conjunctions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“My friends and I” vs. “My friends and me” vs. “Me and my friends”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1133/my-friends-and-i-vs-my-friends-and-me-vs-me-and-my-friends)
>   [Is naming the first person last proper grammar or just proper manners?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4120/is-naming-the-first-person-last-proper-grammar-or-just-proper-manners)

"Julio and I went to the schoolyard." is a valid sentence.

How about "I and Julio went to the schoolyard."?

It's impolite (putting yourself first) and awkward, but is it 
grammatically incorrect?

[I realize the original lyric "see me and Julio..." is a grammatically 
correct imperative sentence]

Comment: The original lyric is "See **you**, me, and Julio" but it's admittedly hard to hear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's impolite (putting yourself first) and awkward, but it is correct grammatically.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think "I and Julio went to the schoolyard." is grammatically incorrect.
It is simply not the common (and polite) form.

See for instance the [personnal pronoun](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/pronouns1.htm#compounding) section on compounding:

> When a personal pronoun is connected by a conjunction to another noun or pronoun, its case does not change.
>   We would write:
>   "`I am taking a course in Asian history`"; if Talitha is also taking that course, we would write:
>   "`Talitha and I are taking a course in Asian history.`"
>   (**Notice that Talitha gets listed before "I" does. This is one of the few ways in which English is a "polite" language.**)
>
> The same is true when the object form is called for:
>   "`Professor Vendetti gave all her books to me`"; if Talitha also received some books, we'd write:
>   "`Professor Vendetti gave all her books to Talitha and me.`"

Comment: The quoted section implies that it *would* be grammatically incorrect to say "I and Talitha". This may have started for reasons of politeness, but became ingrained into the English language.