# use of I and me at the beginning of a sentence

Tags: grammar, personal-pronouns

Which one is correct:

*I and my father are going to the market.*

*Me and my father are going to the market.*

Comment: Neither one is correct.  The second sentence is wrong in that we use objective pronouns as objects of the verb and not subjects.  The first sentence is unusual because no one mentions the nominative pronoun "I" first whenever the verb has two subjects.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Julio and I" vs "I and Julio"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7611/julio-and-i-vs-i-and-julio). Or [“My friends and I” vs. “My friends and me” vs. “Me and my friends”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1133/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second is not grammatical.

The first is grammatical (except that it lacks the verb 'are'), but neither idiomatic, nor conforming to speech etiquette. Politeness requires that one mentions oneself second. So one would normally say:

***My father and I are going to the market.***

In determining whether to say 'he and I', or 'he and me', just mentally omit the 'he'. Clearly one would not say *me am going to the market*, so it has to be 'I'. But one would say *It belongs to my father and me*, since 'I' am no longer the subject of the sentence, and the accusative pronoun is called for.

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly what the OP is asking. The second phrase is grammatical in the sentence *"Did you see me and my father going to the market yesterday"*.

Comment: Thank you very much sir for kind reply. Yes unfortunately I forgot to write the helping verb (are) before the participle.