# When tagging a picture, which statement is correct if it includes yourself and a friend? I was taught friend's name then mine

Tags: grammaticality, pronouns, word-order

> **Duplicate of:**
>   [John, Valencia, and I (or me)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25312/john-valencia-and-i-or-me)
>   [“My friends and I” vs. “My friends and me” vs. “Me and my friends”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1133/my-friends-and-i-vs-my-friends-and-me-vs-me-and-my-friends)
>   [Is naming the first person last proper grammar or just proper manners?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4120/is-naming-the-first-person-last-proper-grammar-or-just-proper-manners)
>   And others.

Which statement is correct when tagging a picture of yourself and a friend? "Barbara and I" or "Me and Barbara?

Comment: I'm asking you for the answer ???

Comment: See these two most excellent answers: [one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1133/should-i-put-myself-last-me-and-you-vs-you-and-me/1197#1197), [two](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4556/who-wants-ice-cream/4655#4655), which actually mention labeling photos. And please search the site before posting. Thank you.

Comment: downvoting this is stupid. The question is fair, why downvote a dupe?

Comment: @bharal: It wasn't my downvote, but, I don't think people are downvoting this because it's a duplicate. Downvoting can be done when a question doesn't show research effort (if you don't beleive me, hover your mouse over the downvote button, and read what it says). The first Google search I did was for "picture captions I or me" and the first result was a nice article by the [Grammar Girl](http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/how-to-write-grammatically-correct-photo-captions.aspx) on this topic (plus [this](http://painintheenglish.com/case/1257)). I don't think these downvotes are unjustified.

Comment: How about just "**with Barbara**"? Isn't "I" superfluous if the recipient can recognize you in the picture? (You are probably not a stranger to them.) :)

Comment: @Kris - and if they know Barbara as well?

Comment: In that case, (out of the scope of the question, though:) the occasion, the place, and the time take over the caption.

Answer (score 1):

*Barbara and I* is very formal. In most cases *Barbara and me* will be appropriate. (You can write *Me and Barabara* if you want to, but it's considered polite to put the other person first.)